# Handling Bounce in Sendgrid smtp API in Python

Tags: python, email, smtp, sendgrid

I am sending marketing emails through sendgrid smtp api via python EmailMultiAlternatives. I want to know how can I handle bounces directly from there to mark particular emails as undeliverable.

The code snippet is:

```
def send1():
    text_content = 'Hi this is the text version'
    connection = get_connection(host=EMAIL_HOST,
                                port=EMAIL_PORT,
                                username=EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                                password=EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD,
                                use_tls=EMAIL_USE_TLS)
    connection.open()
    subject = 'Inviting {0} to join the Business Network of SMEs'.format('surya')
    html_content = template.format('Surya')
    from_email = 'sp@abc.com'
    to = 'abc@gmail.com'
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to], connection=connection)
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
    connection.close()
```

Is it possible to get the response here only after `msg.send()` or is there some other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to respond to events like blocks and bounces is to implement the [event webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html).

You can also poll for the data via the [bounces endpoint](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/bounces.html).

Answer (score 0):

So, For those who might be looking for a solution:

I am using imaplib python package to scrape the inbox (of the mail id through which i am sending the emails) everyday for bounced emails and complaints to get those unwanted emails.

```
def bounce():

    M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.zoho.com')
    M.login('email@emailcom', password)
    M.select()
    line = '(HEADER Subject "Bounce")'
    typ, data = M.uid('search', line)
    if typ != 'OK':
        return
    print(len(data[0].split()))
    for i in data[0].split():

        result, data = M.uid('fetch', i, '(RFC822)')
        raw_email = data[0][1].decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
        emg = email.message_from_string(raw_email)

        w = get_first_text_block(emg)
        emails = re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", str(w), re.I)
```

So Executing the code everyday or every hour will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [sendgrid](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python). The below was written using version 6.4.1.

```
import sendgrid
sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(api_key="<your_key>")
payload = {
    "limit": 100,
    "offset": 0,
}
response = sg.client.suppression.bounces.get(query_params=payload)
```

query_params can be omitted to accept the defaults, there's also start_time and end_time available (need to be integer Unix times).